# Can I use the function for 'decimal minutes with suffix' from the map layout tool (grid) in the field calculator of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, print-composer

I want to generate a table of sites with GPS device conform position markers for field work and use the format 'Degree Minute with Suffix'. I see it is predefined in the 'Map Layout Grid' context to label map coordinates.

Map -> Grid -> 'Draw Coordinates' -> 'Degree Minute with Suffix'

Is there a possibility to use/access the grid labeling function for map grids within the field calculator context?

Comment: Nope. You can use `transform()` and `to_dms()` in order to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Yup, works well can you provide an answer for vote up and closing the question?

Comment: Feel free to answer yourself, time is in short supply for me currently.